# Python peewee не работает join. KeyError

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, join, peewee

Пробую через join получить данные но возникает ошибка

> KeyError: class 'Server2.Models.ChatMembers.ChatMembers'

Пример кода

```
def __get_chat_members(self, id):
     return (ChatMembers
             .select(Users)
             .join(Users, on=(Users.id == ChatMembers.user_id))
             .where(ChatMembers.chat_id == id))

for member in self.__get_chat_members(1):
    print(member.username)
```

ChatMembers модель

```
class ChatMembers(Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = 'chat_members'

id = BigIntegerField(index=True, unique=True)
chat_id = BigIntegerField()
user_id = BigIntegerField()
```

Users модель

```
class Users(Model):
id = BigIntegerField(index=True, unique=True)
username = CharField(unique=True)
password = CharField()
phone = CharField(unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод [naive](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#SelectQuery.naive). Пример:

```
def __get_chat_members(self, id):
    return (ChatMembers
            .select(Users)
            .join(Users, on=(Users.id == ChatMembers.user_id))
            .where(ChatMembers.chat_id == id)
            .naive())
```